# Telegram Bot Api, отправка файла без скачивания

Tags: python, telegram, telebot

Имеется ссылка, к примеру [эта](https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/1771637/74d3e432-323a-4b24-b410-7577ddc99726/s1200). Для отправки этого изображения ботом в телеграме, необходимо сначала получить все байты изображения (по сути, скачать его целиком).

```
import telebot
import requests

bot = telebot.TeleBot('API_TOKEN')

request = requests.get('https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/1771637/74d3e432-323a-4b24-b410-7577ddc99726/s1200')
response = request.content

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_message(message):
    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, response)

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Изображения весят относительно немного. Но для отправки, например, аудио-файла, который весит 8 МБ придётся ждать несколько секунд для его загрузки с сайта и примерно столько же для отправки его пользователю. Как вариант, использовать предпросмотр в сообщении, где будет прикреплённый файл. Но мне необходима именно прямая отправка файла по определённой ссылке без его скачивания сервером.

Для отправки файла используется **bot.send_document()**, где обязательным параметром являются байты отправляемого файла. Но для их получения его необходимо скачать, так как он хранится на другом сайте.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете передать ссылку на изображение и не скачивать его на свой сервер.

***Пример:***

```py
bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, 'https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/1771637/74d3e432-323a-4b24-b410-7577ddc99726/s1200')
```

---

Вот, что сказано об этом в [документации](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendphoto):

> pass an HTTP URL as a String for Telegram to get a photo from the
> Internet, or upload a new photo using multipart/form-data.

А вот как это [реализовано](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/telebot/apihelper.py#L334-L339) в библиотеке:

```py
if util.is_string(photo):
    payload['photo'] = photo
elif util.is_pil_image(photo):
    files = {'photo': util.pil_image_to_file(photo)}
else:
    files = {'photo': photo}
```